# Where to store authentication token in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm using a service with REST api, which provides me an authentication token as the response for the sign in POST request. Where is it better (and secure) to store? This token should be added to each request after that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) to store passwords and tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Use this https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox . Simple way without knowing the apis